# Phi MOA, Chi-Square and Null Hypothesis, What can be learned?

Tags: chi-squared-test, hypothesis-testing, association-measure

In short, is there anything to be learned from performing a [Phi measurement of association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) (MOA) on a Chi-Square test where it failed to reject the null hypothesis?

$$\phi = \sqrt{\chi^2/N}$$

where $\chi^2$ is the value returned by Chi-Square and $N$ is the number of observations.

Or is the phi coefficient only useful on significant tests?

I haven't touched stats in a few years but I couldn't find a explicit remark on the usefulness of a measurement on non-significant tests.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us what a "Phi measurement" is and what "MOA" might stand for?

Comment: Sorry, didn't spell that out very well.  I have always heared it as the Phi measurement of association. or p = (X^2/N)^(1/2).  Where X is the Chi-Square return and N is observations.  The square-root of  Chi-squared divided by observations.